# Binding radio to [checked] in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I'm porting some code where radio button state is bound to a boolean and manually managed. I don't want to rewrite the code to manage a shared *string* value (via ngModel), just want to bind a boolean to the "checked" property and control the checked state in my code. There are times when I need to *reject* a selection, and uncheck the radio box after it has be clicked.

Programmatically unchecking a radio button works fine using regular ol' Javascript ([plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Zi8vtlm7amU1p30lPcXs?p=preview)):

```
<input type="radio" id="radioButton" onclick="uncheckRadioButton()">
<script>
  function uncheckRadioButton() {
     document.getElementById("radioButton").checked = false;
  }
</script>
```

This results in a radio button that can't be checked.

But binding a boolean to `[checked]` in Angular 2 simple doesn't work ([plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Z8z5DdH5bI5iCJtDBvX1?p=preview)):

```
  <input type="radio" [checked]="radioChecked" (click)="onRadioClicked()">
```

It doesn't matter what value "radioChecked" has (here it's hardcoded to false); if you click the radio button, it gets checked.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You can add template variable to your radio input element so you can get a reference to it in your component and change the value:

```
<input type="radio" #myRadio (click)="onRadioClicked()">
```

And then in your component you can change its value:

```
onRadioClicked(myRadio: any) {
    myRadio.checked = false;
}
```

Here's working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ACA27CAkwJh3Y8CEPNbH?p=preview). For some reason, it's not possible to change radio input's value using attribute binding, I'm not sure why.